# How to use dynamic value in ng-template let definition

Tags: angular, ng-template

Currently, I have ng-template defined as below which works well, but I wanted to have the let variable defined with dynamic value, can you please help me how to solve this problem?

**Working**

```html
<ng-template #topTemplate ng-label-tmp let-item="item" let-clear="clear"
  aria-autocomplete="none" let-insideSubItemTop="item.parent.name">
  
  <div class="badge badge-pill df-closable badge-blue">
    {{insideSubItemTop}}
    <button type="button" [badgeEventListener]="[clear, item]">
      <span aria-hidden="true" class="icon-times"></span>
    </button>
  </div>

</ng-template>
```

But I wanted to define the value in ng-template based on the computation done in the component.ts

**Not Working**

`let-insideSubItemTop="{{computedInComponent}}"`

So I tried in my component.ts with
`computedInComponent = 'item.parent.name';`

The above is not working, can some help me how to achieve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pass variable in Angular 2 template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43726749/pass-variable-in-angular-2-template) (+ https://angular.io/api/common/NgTemplateOutlet#properties)

Comment: how are you using your template? is it `ngTemplateOutlet`?